# I've animated the width of an element, but the element's border disappears when the animation starts

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have an element on my new webpage that changes it's width when it shrinks. However, one of the child elements has a `border-bottom` property set, and the border disappears before the animation completes.

I've uploaded my website files to CodeSandbox to demonstrate the problem, as posting the code here would require a full re-write since my scripts are imported as modules.

https://wkkpj.codesandbox.io/

Click on the white arrow icon, on the left side of the page. That icon is in a box. To the right of that, there is another box. That "box to the right" is the box whose border is vanishing. Try expanding and contracting the sidebar a few times, and you will notice the problem.

I've already tried moving the border to a seperate element, and originally, this code did not have a wrapper div. That was just another attempt at fixing the issue.

Comment: It'd be easier/more fun to help you if you provided code we can work with in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you switch the sidebar from `grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr;` to `grid-template-columns: 30px 0px;` If you leave that out you will not have this problem. I made a simple example out of your code:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.toggle')) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  var sidebarLeft = document.getElementById('sidebar-left');
  if (sidebarLeft.classList.contains('clicked')) {
    sidebarLeft.classList.remove('clicked');
  } else {
    sidebarLeft.classList.add('clicked');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#body, #wrapper {
  display: grid;
}

#body{
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "a a a" "b c d" "e e e";
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
}
#header{
  grid-area: a;
}
.sidebar.left {
    grid-area: b;
    width: 240px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.wrapper{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#content {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: #0f111aff;
}
.toggle{
  background: gray;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#sidebar-left.clicked{
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id='body'>
  <div id='header'></div>
  
  <div class='sidebar left' id='sidebar-left'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='toggle'>
       <
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id='content'>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

If you feel you absolutely need the grid template. You can use js to trigger this after .5s (the duration of the transition). I tried doing it with a CSS animation, but it seems that it does not pick up on the `grid-template-rows / grid-template-columns`.

Tip 1 - Always make the most simple example of your problem. It helps if you post the code here or atleast somewhere we can easily edit it.

Tip 2 - Do not use the same ID multiple times in HTML

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I would have EVER found that out myself. I thought setting the columns was necessary to hide the other grid area.

Answer (score 0):

I did some debugging:

When you slide to left, your wrapper does not have an amination. Set transition time to 10 seconds. You will see, that the wrapper shrinks instantly. This does not happen, when sliding back to mid. That's my the border disappears.

The rest is up to you ;)